# Why does documentation search fail on substrings?

Tags: documentation, searching

For example many times I have to type the full string exactly which defeats the point of a search, so perhaps this is a bug?

[image]

Comment: Entering `createdoc*` into the search field will do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

In the Wolfram Language Documentation Center from the menu Help > Wolfram Documentation, I use wild card characters to broaden the search. For example `CreateDoc*`. Alternatively, use Ctrl-k to autocomplete a search entry. In a notebook, I use, for example, `?*Button*`.